# UILabel fell under UIImageView

Tags: xcode

So i've got a custom TableViewCell with UIImageView as a bg and 2 labels on top of it.
Everything was fine, but after changing text color on labels they seem to fall under UIImageView, changing opacity on UIImageView makes them visible.

I can't even imagine from where to start getting my Labels back on top layer, help.

it was all done drag'n'drop style

edit: after closing and re-opening the project labels are indeed under imageview on Storyboard

Comment: do you have your cell created with xib file?

Comment: yes, it was all made using drag'n'drop, not programmatically

Comment: Just reorder your UIImageView under labels

Comment: omg, i just remembered where to do it, after reading your post) so embarrassing, thanks!